# wxPython: Update wx.ListBox list

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wx.ListBox in a python program, and I wan't to change out the list in it on a wx.Timer update. I have the timer working, I just don't know how to change out the list that it displays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here's an example](http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216484.html#) for modifying a ListBox.
Generally, it uses the `Append` and `Clear` methods of ListBox. You can call those in your timer handler.

Since `ListBox` derives from `ItemContainer`, see more item modification methods [here](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ItemContainer-class.html).